# Stripe Payment Incomplete when administrator's account of India

Tags: stripe-payments, status

I have Implemented stripe into my Angular project with `Laravel` BackEnd.

The Problem is with Plan Amount. Here is some scenario in which case, stripe payment is failing. I don't know why stripe is failing in that scenarios.

`Scenario 1 : 
---------------------------------------------------------------------`

My Stripe account of Country : **United State**

My plans are created in Stripe Site (Currency) : **Dolor**

`Result :`

Payment with all countries card will result in **success**
 of payment

`Scenario 2 : 
---------------------------------------------------------------------`

My Stripe account of country : **India**

My plans are created in Stripe Site (currency) : **Dolor**

`Result :`

1. Pay by Indian card will **fail** the payment.
2. Pay by Other country card Will **success** the payment

`Scenario 3 : 
--------------------------------------------------------------------`

My Stripe Account of country : **India**

My plans are created in Stripe site (Currency) : **Rupee**

`Result`

1. Pay by Indian Card will **Success** the payment
2. Pay by Another Country's card will **Success** the payment But Another countri's people will see plans in rupees. This is not fair.

IS There any solution that able to create stripe plans with **Dolor** Currency and able to make payment with **Indian Card** ?

Comment: What error message are you getting when you try to do this?  You may also just want to reach out to Stripe Support (https://support.stripe.com/contact/email) so they can help.